# How can I go to the next page with the api?

Tags: javascript, api

hello everyone i am new to javascript. I'm having a problem with the API, can you help me? Thank you from now.

api_url is not updating for index. Next page 2,3,4  It isn't happening. But accepts 1...

```js
var index = 1;
const main = document.getElementById("main");
const API_URL =
  "https://api.themoviedb.org/3/discover/movie?sort_by=popularity.desc&api_key=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx&page=" + index;

next.addEventListener("click", () => {
  index = index + 1;
  getMovies(API_URL);
});

prev.addEventListener("click", () => {
  if (index == 1 || index == 0) {
    alert("not working");
  } else {
    index = index - 1;
    getMovies(
      "https://api.themoviedb.org/3/discover/movie?sort_by=popularity.desc&api_key=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx&page=" + index
    );
  }
});
```

This is working. But How does the above work?

```js
var index = 1;
const main = document.getElementById("main");
const API_URL =
  "https://api.themoviedb.org/3/discover/movie?sort_by=popularity.desc&api_key=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx&page=" + index;

next.addEventListener("click", () => {
  index = index + 1;
      getMovies(
      "https://api.themoviedb.org/3/discover/movie?sort_by=popularity.desc&api_key=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx&page=" + index
    );
});

prev.addEventListener("click", () => {
  if (index == 1 || index == 0) {
    alert("not working");
  } else {
    index = index - 1;
    getMovies(
      "https://api.themoviedb.org/3/discover/movie?sort_by=popularity.desc&api_key=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx&page=" + index
    );
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The first example is not working because API_URL is a const, so it wont change. You should try using a let.

```js
var index = 1;
const main = document.getElementById("main");
let API_URL =
  "https://api.themoviedb.org/3/discover/movie?sort_by=popularity.desc&api_key=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx&page=" + index;

next.addEventListener("click", () => {
  index = index + 1;
  getMovies(API_URL);
});

prev.addEventListener("click", () => {
  if (index == 1 || index == 0) {
    alert("not working");
  } else {
    index = index - 1;
    getMovies(
      "https://api.themoviedb.org/3/discover/movie?sort_by=popularity.desc&api_key=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx&page=" + index
    );
  }
});
```

Comment: I've tried. It didn't happen. It always shows 1.but index is increasing.

Comment: https://prnt.sc/4n1yeFAGtrhd